# Can't get input value with click event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am dynamically creating a table which includes some dynamically generated buttons. I have done the same thing before using `POST` and it worked. Now I'm using AJAX so I need to get the value of the hidden `form` element via the click event.  But, it always gives me the first value (first row/form).

Below is example of stripped down code.

Must I have a different name for each button? If so, how would I bind all those to a click event?

```
<pre><code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("click", "input[name='vsu']", function(event){
                    console.log('sliste'+$("input[name='sliste']").val());  
                    event.preventDefault();
                });                     
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="slist"> 
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>user1</td>  
                    <td>
                        <form>
                            <input type="hidden" name="sliste" value="1">
                            <input name="vsu1" type="submit" value="view">
                        </form>
                    </td>        
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>user2</td>  
                    <td>
                        <form>
                            <input type="hidden" name="sliste" value="2">
                            <input name="vsu2" type="submit" value="view">
                        </form>
                    </td>        
                </tr>    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</pre></code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the input element which is the previous sibling of the clicked button so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "input[name='vsu']", function (event) {
        console.log('sliste' + $(this).prev("input[name='sliste']").val());
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When you use `$("input[name='sliste']")` as the selector it will find all the input elements with the given name then when you use `.val()` as a getter it will return the value of the first element in the given set of elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "input[name='vsu']", function(event) {
    console.log('sliste' + $(this).prev("input[name='sliste']").val());
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="slist">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>user1</td>  
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="hidden" name="sliste" value="1">
          <!-- changed the button type since the code snippet does not allow submit requests-->
          <input name="vsu" type="button" value="view">
        </form>
      </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>user2</td>  
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="hidden" name="sliste" value="2">
          <input name="vsu" type="button" value="view">
        </form>
      </td>        
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```